# how to make a list by same element

Tags: python, list, element

For example, there are

`list0 = []`,

`list1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'cow', 'horse', 'mouse']`,

`list2 = ['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4']`

And I want to fill `list0` for `list2`'s elements, which have length of `list1`.
So `list0` will be

`list0 = ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1']` or

`list0 = ['b1', 'b1', 'b1', 'b1', 'b1']` like this.

I think it will work by use `list0 = list2[i] * len(list1)` but doesn't work.

Comment: Try: `list0 = [list2[i]] * len(list1)`

Comment: @XYZT got the right solution, but `i` needs to be defined.  OP needs to decide which index they want since it wasn't clarified in the question.

Comment: @XYZT Thanks! It was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, just add square brackets around `list[i]`:

```
list1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'cow', 'horse', 'mouse']

list2 = ['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4']

list0 = [list2[0]]*len(list1)

print(list0)
```

Output:

```
['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1']
```

Answer (score 0):

## You've said everything right! Try this:

Compare this *working* code to what you have.

```py
list1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'cow', 'horse', 'mouse']
list2 = ['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4']

index_of_filler = 0  # index of elem in list2 with which list0 should be made

list0 =[list2[index_of_filler]]* len(list1)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This returns a string `'a1a1a1a1'`. This is not what OP wants.

Comment: Whoops, made the fix.